# Concern and field Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, activesupport-concern

i want to create a concern like this:

```
module Geolocalizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Mongoid

  included do
    attr_accessible :lat, :lng
    field :lat
    field :lng
  end
end
```

And than include it in my model :

```
class Store
   include Mongoid::Document
   include 'Geolocalizable'

   field :name, type: String
   field :address, type: String
end
```

But in my stores/new.html.erb
this line gives me an error

```
f.text_filed :lat
```

undefined method `lat' for #Store:0xae6bb58

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's wrong argument type, it should be: `include Geolocalizable`

Comment: Thank you! I'am really bad :/